# How do I match a list with a dict and time related values?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I got this in my `views.py`:

```
# Get the amount of kilo attached to products
product_data = {}
for product in ProductSpy.objects.all():
    product_data[product.id] = {"product_id": product.product_id, "kilo": product.kilo}

# Get quantity bought of each product
total_qty_bought = self.order_item_model.objects.values("product").annotate(Sum("quantity"))
```

​
​
So in my `product_data` dump I got this here:

```
6: {'product_id': 32, 'kilo': Decimal('25.00')},
```

and in my `total_qty_bought` dump I got this:

```
{'product': 32, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('5')},
```

Now as the `product_id` match the `product`, I want it to return `125`, as we got `5` times the quantity of `25` kilo.
In my `total_qty_bought` dump you'd find id's not relevant, so if they dont match any in my `product_data` dump, I want them ignored.

What is the smartest way to achieve this?

## print dump:

product_data:

```
{4: {'product_id': 30, 'kilo': Decimal('25.00')}, 5: {'product_id': 31, 'kilo': Decimal('25.00')}, 6: {'product_id': 32, 'kilo': Decimal('25.00')}, 7: {'product_id': 33, 'kilo': Decimal('25.00')}, 8: {'product_id': 37, 'kilo': Decimal('15.00')}, 9: {'product_id': 38, 'kilo': Decimal('15.00')}, 10: {'product_id': 39, 'kilo': Decimal('10.00')}, 11: {'product_id': 40, 'kilo': Decimal('10.00')}, 12: {'product_id': 41, 'kilo': Decimal('5.00')}, 13: {'product_id': 42, 'kilo': Decimal('2.50')}, 14: {'product_id': 43, 'kilo': Decimal('5.00')}, 15: {'product_id': 44, 'kilo': Decimal('2.50')}, 17: {'product_id': 50, 'kilo': Decimal('2.50')}, 18: {'product_id': 51, 'kilo': Decimal('5.00')}, 19: {'product_id': 52, 'kilo': Decimal('10.00')}, 20: {'product_id': 53, 'kilo': Decimal('15.00')}, 21: {'product_id': 55, 'kilo': Decimal('15.00')}, 22: {'product_id': 56, 'kilo': Decimal('10.00')}, 23: {'product_id': 57, 'kilo': Decimal('5.00')}, 24: {'product_id': 58, 'kilo': Decimal('2.50')}}
​
```

total_qty_bought:

```
<QuerySet [{'product': 42, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('5')}, {'product': 41, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('3')}, {'product': 51, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('13')}, {'product': 50, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('34')}, {'product': 49, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('1')}, {'product': 40, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('2')}, {'product': 43, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('10')}, {'product': 52, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('12')}, {'product': 32, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('5')}, {'product': 53, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('2')}, {'product': 38, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('1')}, {'product': 55, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('1')}, {'product': 56, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('10')}, {'product': 58, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('60')}, {'product': 44, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('16')}, {'product': 57, 'quantity__sum': Decimal('28')}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    product_data = {}
    for product in ProductSpy.objects.all():
        product_data[product.product_id] = product.kilo
   
    # Get quantity bought of each product
    total_qty_bought = self.order_item_model.objects.values("product").annotate(Sum("quantity"))

    our_total = {}
    for qty in total_qty_bought:
        product_id = qty['product']
        quantity = int(qty["quantity__sum"])
        try:
            kilos = quantity * product_data[product_id]
            our_total[product_id] = kilos
            print(f"Product_id: {product_id} - Kilos: {kilos}")
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Product_id {product_id} not found in product_data!")
```

Here's the solution.